# In Tiny Tower can a Bitizen have a skill level of 9 in all 5 categories?

Tags: tiny-tower

I wonder if anyone has seen any Bitizen that has a skill level of 9 in all 5 categories. I've only seen some have three 9s, but never more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Their skill levels are given at random so it is definitely possible. Personally I've never seen one because it is rare, but I have seen someone with 0 skill in all 5 categories. I was tempted to keep the guy because it was so absurd

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen it but as the other answer said it is possible, I have a bitizen with three nines and two ones and another with three nines and two zeros.